# Connecting to SQL Server on AWS RDS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an SQL Server running on an AWS RDS Instance. I can connect fine using SQL SMgr on my local machine but I get an error message from an application I run on my local machine which needs to publish data to the DB. I've read some stuff about VPCs and security groups but wanted to know if this is actually possible.

The error message reads:

```
COM Error
Code = 80004005
Code meaning = unspecified error
Source = Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server
Description = Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with windows authentication.
```

Comment: The error suggests you are trying to use Windows auth.  What kind of app is it, and how did you configure the authentication?  What auth scheme do you use in SSMS?

Comment: I thought that too, but it's not my app, just one I use for work. If it uses Windows Auth on my local machine is there anyway of getting the info onto the RDS?

Comment: I don't believe SQL Server in RDS supports Windows Auth, according to  [Amazon's doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_SQLServer.html).  If you set up a database user and configure the app with a connection string for username/password auth, that should work.